# C# Enqueue Failure

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

I have a simple logging mechanism that should be thread safe.  It works most of the time, but every now and then I get an exception on this line, "_logQ.Enqueue(s);" that the queue is not long enough.  Looking in the debugger there are sometimes just hundreds of items, so I can't see it being resources.  The queue is supposed to expand as needed.  If I catch the exception as opposed to letting the debugger pause at the exception I see the same error.  Is there something not thread safe here?  I don't even know how to start debugging this.

```
    static void ProcessLogQ(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            while (_logQ.Count > 0)
            {
                var s = _logQ.Dequeue();
                string dir="";
                Type t=Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime");
                if (t!=null)
                {
                    dir ="/var/log";
                }else
                {
                    dir = @"c:\log";
                    if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                }
                if (Directory.Exists(dir))
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(dir, "admin.log"), DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss ") + s + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            _isProcessingLogQ = false;
        }
    }

    public static void Log(string s) {
        if (_logQ == null)
            _logQ = new Queue<string> { };

        lock (_logQ)
            _logQ.Enqueue(s);
        if (!_isProcessingLogQ) {
            _isProcessingLogQ = true;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessLogQ);
        }
    }
```

Note that the threads all call Log(string s).  ProcessLogQ is private to the logger class.

*** Edit ***
I made a mistake in not mentioning that this is in a .NET 3.5 environment, therefore I can't use Task or ConcurrentQueue.  I am working on fixes for the current example within .NET 3.5 constraints.

** Edit *
I believe I have a thread-safe version for .NET 3.5 listed below. I start the logger thread once from a single thread at program start, so there is only one thread running to log to the file (t is a static Thread):

```
    static void ProcessLogQ()
    {
        while (true) {
            try {
                lock (_logQ);
                while (_logQ.Count > 0) {
                    var s = _logQ.Dequeue ();
                    string dir = "../../log";
                    if (!Directory.Exists (dir))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory (dir);
                    if (Directory.Exists (dir)) {
                        File.AppendAllText (Path.Combine (dir, "s3ol.log"), DateTime.Now.ToString ("hh:mm:ss ") + s + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
            } finally {
            }
            Thread.Sleep (1000);
        }
    }

    public static void startLogger(){
        lock (t) {
            if (t.ThreadState != ThreadState.Running)
                t.Start ();
        }
    }
    private static void multiThreadLog(string msg){
        lock (_logQ)
            _logQ.Enqueue(msg);
    }
```

Comment: Any reason for the down votes?  I researched as well as I knew how for the topic and put all the information together quite clearly.  Are we supposed to be experts to ask questions... so in that case we then wouldn't need to ask?

Comment: if you're dequeuing in a loop why are you using threads?  You could really just create a class that uses instances and resolve this using much cleaner code.

Comment: @CoffeeMuncher, There are multiple-threads putting messages in the queue, and the logging thread must be in its own thread so that other threads are not held up.  It is the classic case for multi-threading.  I have solved the problem, BTW, and it is working great.  I created my own ConcurrentQueue.

Comment: It's fine that it has to be it's own thread, but for the sake of simplicity and cleanness you don't have to have everything as a static is my point.  Placing a lock while processing in a loop will still hold up other threads from writing, that's the whole point of a lock, you want the capture the queue in the given state so you can act on it.  What you really want to look at is a producer...consumer model

Comment: @CoffeeMuncher, ok, now I see what you are saying.  It is static because it is used all over the code for logging, so we didn't want to have an object instantiated each time.  I think I should post again, or update with my solution, so that we can review what I'm actually doing now.  I'd like your input on the actual solution.  What is posted here was when I really didn't know what I was doing (the point of the question).  I think I know much better now, but you never know what you don't know. - And for clarity the "edit" above still was not the final one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the TaskParallel Library. All the hard work is already done for you.  If you're doing this to learn about multithreading read up on locking techniques and pros and cons of each.

Further, you're checking if _logQ is null outside your lock statement, from what I can deduce it's a static field that you're not initializing inside a static constructor.  You can avoid doing this null check (which should be inside a lock, it's critical code!) you can ensure thread-safety by making it a static readonly and initializing it inside the static constructor.

Further, you're not properly handling queue states.  Since there's no lock during the check of the queue count it could vary on every iteration.  You're missing a lock as your dequeuing items.

Excellent resource:
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/

Answer (score 1):

For a thread-safe queue, you should use the ConcurrentQueue instead:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info on this.  I forgot to mention that I have a constraint of .NET 3.5.  I've posted an edit update for what I believe is a valid thread-safe solution in the .NET 3.5 environment.